# convert an arrayList<Object[]> into a nested array

Tags: java

This is the following idea:

```
List<Object[]> ret = new ArrayList<>();
ret.add(new Object[]{"a", 1});
Object[][] obj = (Object[][]) ret.toArray();
```

but it doesn't work: `toArray` returns Object[]

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why would it be `[][]`?

Comment: each element in the list would be an `Object[]`. Then, I want to cast it into what it really is

Comment: I've updated the question with the error :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a version of [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) that accepts an array as an argument. This allows you to specify what type of array you want returned.

```
Object[][] obj = ret.toArray(new Object[0][]);
```

You can pass in an array big enough to hold the contents of your list; or you can pass in an array of zero size and the list implementation should return a new array of the same type as the one you passed in.

Comment: yes! That's what's missing: passing the array into which the elements of the list are to be stored. Worked like charm.